# Is it possible to use OCI Object Storage with aws-sdk-s3 gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, amazon-s3

I created a key/secret pair and Pre-Authenticated Request and updated storage.yml to use it with rails active storage + provided an endpoint.

This is the error that I'm getting when trying to upload a file.
`Seahorse::Client::NetworkingError (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (unspecified certificate verification error)):`

The endpoint looks like this `https://my-namespace.compat.objectstorage.eu-frankfurt-1.oraclecloud.com`

Answer (score 0):

It's been awhile since you posted this, but since I just recently ran into this, I'll share what worked for me in case it's helpful to you (or others).

The `force_path_style: true` parameter in the Active Storage settings (config/storage.yml) is likely missing.  The [OCI S3-compatibility interface](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Object/Tasks/s3compatibleapi.htm) looks for the bucket name in the path, not the hostname (which this option sets).

Here's an example:

```
# config/storage.yml

oci:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: <%= ENV['OCI_KEY'] %>
  secret_access_key: <%= ENV['OCI_SECRET'] %>
  bucket: <BUCKET NAME>-<%= Rails.env %>
  region: <%= ENV['OCI_REGION'] %>
  endpoint: https://<%= ENV['OCI_NAMESPACE'] %>.compat.objectstorage.<%= ENV['OCI_REGION'] %>.oraclecloud.com
  force_path_style: true
```